# Каким образом узнать нажата ли клавиша tab в python3.6.1

Tags: python, python-3.x

Каким образом узнать нажата ли клавиша tab в python3.6.1?
Можно конечно попробовать через tkinter. Но я бы хотел как то по другому.

Comment: pygame в помощь!

Comment: в какой программе? (GUI, консольная) Откуда ввод? (при активном окне в GUI, построчный ввод в консоли, посимвольный ввод в консоле? Ввод через pipe?) Чем конкрентно tkinter не устраивает? Какие критерии?

Comment: Ввод в консоли.

Comment: kbhit + getch == `b'\t'`

Comment: это я так понимаю надо сделать через msvcrt?

Comment: в винде это будет через msvcrt